# How many people will be there VS How many people will there be there

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference:

> 1) How many people will be there?
>
> 2) How many people will there be there?

Comment: Remember to add a question mark at the end of each sentence.

Comment: Yeah, of course=)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning. The first is more concise and easier to construe. It is what a skilled writer would publish and what a careful speaker would usually say. But people do not always formulate spoken (or even written) sentences with skill and care.

Comment: The second one is correct without the last word "there", right?

Comment: 1) But if the first one is easier why is it used by a skilled person?
If a person is skilled he has to use more difficult constructions.

2) No, it's with the second 'there"

Comment: @TasneemZh Yes, it would be correct, but it would have a slightly different meaning in that it would simply be a question about number rather than a question about number in a specific place ot at specific event.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko With some important exceptions, skilled writers generally use the **clearest** expression, which means the expression **easiest** to understand. The usual purpose of writing is to explain or to persuade rather than to baffle. 99 times out of a 100, use "redden" rather than "incarnadine:" most people are too lazy to use a dictionary. And if your purpose is to deceive or confuse, you certainly do not want to force your audience to pause for thought.

Comment: @JeffMorrow but they are different - "redden" and "incarnadine", I translated. The first one is to make read but the latter one is to make slightly red. It's different=)

But then why do we say:
1) "How many people will there be"? instead of 2) "How many people will be there?"
Or it can be worse:
3) "How many people will at school be ?" instead of "How many people will be at school?

Comment: @JeffMorrow I am very meticulous about English. I would like to know all the rules, all the phrasal verbs, all the nuances and details, I am not lazy, I want to swallow all the English up. I live by It=)

Comment: @Michael I was not trying to imply that **you** are lazy. I was instead asserting that your **audience** will frequently be lazy. You looked up "incarnidine," but will your audience bother to do so? We usually speak or write for an audience, and, if you want to be undrstood, you frequently need to temper the wind to the shorn lambs. So, as a matter of style, I suggest that you generally use the simplest means to express your intent completely and concisely. It will usually be better to say "redden slightly" than "incarnidine" if you want to be understood. But style is a matter of opinion.